# Why isn't this object becoming transparent in the render?

Tags: transparency

I'm new to Blender and trying to make an image. I'm almost there but something is confusing me. Right now, I have this blue rectangle that I want in the same plane as the other objects. For example, here it is from a couple angles:

[image]
[image]

and rendered:

[image]

Now, I want that blue rectangle to be mostly transparent, so you can see the rest of the shape that it coincides with very clearly. So, I went to the materials tab with that object selected, clicked the transparency box, and messed with the alpha parameter, making it very low:

[image]

Now, when I render it, it does look different...but isn't actually transparent:

[image]

what am I missing here? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Those transparency settings are for viewport only, not materials or rendering. How are you rendering this?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos just hitting F12, which does Blender Render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your transparency to *Mask*. To quote the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/transparency.html):

> This option simply masks the Background. It uses the alpha channel to
>   mix the color of each pixel on the active object plane with the color
>   of the corresponding background pixel, according to the alpha channel
>   of the pixel. Thus for alpha = 1, the object color is seen – the
>   object is completely opaque; but if alpha = 0, only the background is
>   seen – the object is transparent (but note that any other object
>   behind the active object disappears).

Essentially, any object behind a 'Mask' object will not be visible.
Instead, set the transparency type to *Z Transparency* or *Raytrace*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that works! I just have one detail I want to change still (and I'd like to avoid making another thread); even when I set alpha = 0.02, it's very transparent but it's making the object behind it very dark, nearly black in the render. It seems like the object (the squiggle) should appear nearly as it does in the section not covered by the transparent block...what's the deal? Thanks!

Comment: I do suggest asking a new, separate question, however, I think the object behind needs 'Receive transparent shadows' enabled in the 'Shadow' panel. As for this answer, if you feel it has answered your question you can 'accept' it. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

In the material panel, Set transparency mode from `Mask` to `Z Transparency`. This will allow objects behind it to show through.

Mask is used to blend the material with the sky color, if I remember correctly.